# Karma Test Runner, GUI?

Tags: user-interface, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have newly discovered Karma and was wondering if command line is the only option I have to run it, as "Webstorm" is not an IDE my team will use (due to some xyz reasons).

For such a useful tool as Karma, command line is not an option I want to give the fresh breed of developers in my team. Ain't their any opensource projects targeting a GUI for the tool for it to work independently on multiple platforms (mac, windows etc.)?

Also how should I go about making my own version of GUI for the tool, so that the same can be run as a widget on both Mac and Windows platforms.

Comment: You could use the karma API to programmatically spawn the server. Just start a karma server and set the `singleRun` flag to `true` in the config file: of course you can bind a button to trigger it - or just enable the `watch` flag. For the full set of flags in the configuration file see: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html

Comment: If you can use [brackets](http://brackets.io/) there's a [karma plugin](https://github.com/artoale/karma-brackets) for it ;) I've never tried it but it looks fine.

Comment: Will try the brackets plugin and let you know!!!, thanks.

Comment: Just tried Brackets (Ubuntu) and it fails to launch the Karma server. Netbeans (latest dev version), however, is able to launch Karma and the tests run fine. Also it collects the coverage data when you enable the karma-coverage module.